# Do any one has timing diagram for SD card multiple block read in SPI mode?

Tags: sd-card, microchip

I am trying to read data from SD card using Multiple block read command. In between sectors I see multiple junk characters, otherwise the data is fine. I am reading out the the two CRC bytes in between sectors. I have tried putting delay between two sector reads, but did not help. 
Did anybody face this before? I somebody has a packet flow diagram, even that would be okay.